# Archive files by age using tar command

Tags: find, tar, archive

H All,

I am trying to archive files older than specific duration, when I am trying to untar the tar file it retains the directory structure from root folder.
I don't want to retain parent folders

command used :

```
find /home/prj/myfolder/* -mtime 1 -type f | 
    while read file; 
    do
        tar -Pcvzf archive.tar.gz --remove-files "$file"
    done
```

Problem: File location is /home/prj/myfolder/abc/a.txt when I untar archive.tar.gz it contains /home/prj/myfolder/abc/a.txt dir stucture.

I am expecting abc/a.txt

Answer (score 4):

Drop the "/home/prj/myfolder/*" and use "cd /home/prj/myfolder/" to navigate to that location.

```
cd /home/prj/myfolder/
find . -mtime 1 -type f | 
    while read file; 
    do
        tar -Pcvzf archive.tar.gz --remove-files "$file"
    done
```

The files will then be stored with a relative path.

Comment: I using "/home/prj/myfolder/*"  since I want to recursively iterate all sub folders under /home/prj/myfolder/  .If I manully use cd then script would be hardcoded. Can u please suggeste any other alternative way so that iteration would be dynamic ?

Comment: and how is that different from the "cd" and "."?

Comment: If I use cd /home/prj/myfolder/ , if their is a file in /home/prj/myfolder/demo/temp/b2.txt .The tar file contains folder structure from demo/temp/b2.txt. My requirement is it should have only temp/b2.txt I dont want demo folder.In solutions provided by you it maintain folder sturcture after myfolder(/demo/)  .I am looking for a generic solution if I use  cd /home/prj/myfolder/ it would be scenario specific

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the solution in Rinzwind's answer. There's no real reason to avoid the `cd`; especially if you put this in a shell script, as the `cd` will affect just the script, not the shell you call the script from.

If you really really don't wan't to use `cd`, you can use `tar`s `--transform` option:

```
gbl@roran:~$ tar -cf /tmp/archive.tar /home/gbl/Temp/a.out
gbl@roran:~$ tar -tf /tmp/archive.tar
home/gbl/Temp/a.out

gbl@roran:~$ tar --transform 's/^home\/gbl//' -cf /tmp/archive2.tar /home/gbl/Temp/a.out
gbl@roran:~$ tar -tf /tmp/archive2.tar
/Temp/a.out

gbl@roran:~$ tar --transform 's/^home\/gbl\///' -cf /tmp/archive3.tar /home/gbl/Temp/a.out
gbl@roran:~$ tar -tf /tmp/archive3.tar
Temp/a.out
```

I omitted some `tar: Removing leading '/' from member names` messages here as they don't contribute to the answer.

Use any `sed` regular expression for the transformation, read the manual for a few more options.

There's also `--strip-components` to remove that many path components from the start of the file name, but it works on extraction only, not when you create an archive.

However, this is restricted to gnu tar, so you'll be ok on Linux, but probably not whenever you switch to MacOS, Solaris, or AIX. Which is another reason to avoid it, especially as there's an easy different solution (`cd` first).